# how to get fields from the profile information with bp_member_profile_data

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am having some difficulties on trying this buddypress code to work:

```
   <?php $args = array(
            'field'   => 'Location',   
            'user_id' => $curauth->ID           
        ); ?>
   <?php  bp_member_profile_data($args); ?>
```

it just doesn't display anything for me. Am i doing something wrong?.
I am running this code in the author wordpress page.
Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work:

```
<?php 
 $location = xprofile_get_field_data( "Location" , $curauth->ID );  
?>
```

actually it works for sure, cause I used it several times! :)

I never used the function `bp_member_profile_data($args)` but I guess it works only inside a loop.

I hope this helped!

Comment: hi thanks for your reply... I commented this line out : '$user_id = 0;' , on the bp_members_template.php, and it works... i just i am not sure if this is the right way to do things :S

Comment: HI! I think this solution works better than mine because i dont want to change the original code! THANKS!